# how to clean a [RegularExpression] MVC message with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I do have a MVC form with eight inputs, one of them is a search textbox that in case finds the employee´ security number fills the other seven inputs with the due information and it may happens that the user enters a non valid security number format so the search inputs shows a message using dataannotations notifying the format is not valid and everythings works fine and there is also a clean all the inputs button (it uses jQuery) and it must clean the text/value entered in the seach input and all the others form inputs and it also works

But my problem comes when the user enters an invalid security number in the search input field and click search, the MVC shows an invalid format message specified in the [RegularExpression] property and when I click the clean button it doesn´t dissapear and it must dissapear because when I clean the form all the inputs must be clean, this is the security number property

```
 [Required(ErrorMessage = "Especificar numero de ISSS a consultar")]
        [Display(Name = "Numero ISSS")]
        [RegularExpression("([0-9]{9})", ErrorMessage = "formato incorrecto de numero de ISSS")]
        public string ISSSBuscar { get; set; }
```

I have managed to make the [required] message dissapears but the format message always appears when click the clean all the inputs, how can I do to not show the [regularExpression] message?

this is my jQuery code, the required remove message works but the RegularExpression message always appears

```
 function Limpiar() {
            $("#idISSSBuscar").rules("remove", "RegularExpression");
            $("#idISSSBuscar").rules("remove", "required");
```

Comment: I did find the solution:  $('.field-validation-error').text("")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may try with the following code:

```
function Limpiar() {
  //Removes validation from input-fields
        $('.input-validation-error').addClass('input-validation-valid');
        $('.input-validation-error').removeClass('input-validation-error');
        //Removes validation message after input-fields
        $('.field-validation-error').addClass('field-validation-valid');
        $('.field-validation-error').removeClass('field-validation-error');
        //Removes validation summary 
        $('.validation-summary-errors').addClass('validation-summary-valid');
        $('.validation-summary-errors').removeClass('validation-summary-errors');
}
```

Hope it will help to solve your problem , kindly let me know your thoughts or feedbacks

Thanks

Karthik